# Network Adapter Information in C++

Tags: c++, windows, networking

On Windows 8, is there any standard function I can use in C in order to get a list of IP addresses and netmasks of each Network Interface Card that handles Ethernet in the system? The only other way I can think of getting such information is by parsing the output of `ipconfig`, but I really don't want to go down that route in C++.

Comment: @keyser if you could answer with some code that uses IP Helper, then I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: Would getaddrinfo(3) help?

Comment: @user3813353 no, because I'm using Windows and not Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft has something called [The IP Helper API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366073%28VS.85%29.aspx). Their documentation is very thorough, and the [Getting Started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366028(v=vs.85).aspx) page contains a few basic examples.

Here's an example of [GetAdaptersInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366314(v=vs.85).aspx):

**Edit**: On XP and later, `GetAdaptersInfo()` is deprecated, use  [`GetAdaptersAddresses()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915(v=vs.85).aspx) instead (credit goes to Remy Lebeau).

```
PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pAdapter = pAdapterInfo;
while (pAdapter) {
    printf("Adapter Name: %s\n", pAdapter->AdapterName);
    printf("Adapter Desc: %s\n", pAdapter->Description);
    printf("\tAdapter Addr: \t");
    for (UINT i = 0; i < pAdapter->AddressLength; i++) {
        if (i == (pAdapter->AddressLength - 1))
            printf("%.2X\n",(int)pAdapter->Address[i]);
        else
            printf("%.2X-",(int)pAdapter->Address[i]);
    }
    printf("IP Address: %s\n", pAdapter->IpAddressList.IpAddress.String);
    printf("IP Mask: %s\n", pAdapter->IpAddressList.IpMask.String);
    printf("\tGateway: \t%s\n", pAdapter->GatewayList.IpAddress.String);
    printf("\t***\n");
    if (pAdapter->DhcpEnabled) {
        printf("\tDHCP Enabled: Yes\n");
        printf("\t\tDHCP Server: \t%s\n", pAdapter->DhcpServer.IpAddress.String);
    }
    else
      printf("\tDHCP Enabled: No\n");

  pAdapter = pAdapter->Next;
}
```

Here's the part regarding [extracting network parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366351(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
    FIXED_INFO *pFixedInfo;
    IP_ADDR_STRING *pIPAddr;

    ULONG ulOutBufLen;
    DWORD dwRetVal;

    pFixedInfo = (FIXED_INFO *) malloc(sizeof (FIXED_INFO));
    ulOutBufLen = sizeof (FIXED_INFO);

    if (GetNetworkParams(pFixedInfo, &ulOutBufLen) == ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW) {
        free(pFixedInfo);
        pFixedInfo = (FIXED_INFO *) malloc(ulOutBufLen);
        if (pFixedInfo == NULL) {
            printf("Error allocating memory needed to call GetNetworkParams\n");
        }
    }

   printf("\tHost Name: %s\n", pFixedInfo->HostName);
        printf("\tDomain Name: %s\n", pFixedInfo->DomainName);
        printf("\tDNS Servers:\n");
        printf("\t\t%s\n", pFixedInfo->DnsServerList.IpAddress.String);

        pIPAddr = pFixedInfo->DnsServerList.Next;
        while (pIPAddr) {
            printf("\t\t%s\n", pIPAddr->IpAddress.String);
            pIPAddr = pIPAddr->Next;
        }

        printf("\tNode Type: ");
        switch (pFixedInfo->NodeType) {
        case 1:
            printf("%s\n", "Broadcast");
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("%s\n", "Peer to peer");
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("%s\n", "Mixed");
            break;
        case 8:
            printf("%s\n", "Hybrid");
            break;
        default:
            printf("\n");
        }

        printf("\tNetBIOS Scope ID: %s\n", pFixedInfo->ScopeId);

        if (pFixedInfo->EnableRouting)
            printf("\tIP Routing Enabled: Yes\n");
        else
            printf("\tIP Routing Enabled: No\n");

        if (pFixedInfo->EnableProxy)
            printf("\tWINS Proxy Enabled: Yes\n");
        else
            printf("\tWINS Proxy Enabled: No\n");

        if (pFixedInfo->EnableDns)
            printf("\tNetBIOS Resolution Uses DNS: Yes\n");
        else
            printf("\tNetBIOS Resolution Uses DNS: No\n");
```

There's also `GetInterfaceInfo` and much more.

Comment: All my program needs to know is each Ethernet adapter's IP address and netmask. Can you edit the code to show how that information can be retrieved?

Comment: I added some sample code using `GetAdaptersInfo`, but you should probably skim through the documentation.

Comment: Thanks! I think the top code sample is what I need.

Comment: On XP and later, `GetAdaptersInfo()` is deprecated, use  [`GetAdaptersAddresses()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915(v=vs.85).aspx) instead.

Comment: Hi everyone, I am looking for something in Linux for GetAdaptersInfo() and GetAdaptersAddresses() . For GetAdaptersAddresses() I found out that getifaddrs() will do the same functionality. But I could not found out anything related to GetAdaptersInfo() to get per adapter information. can anyone suggest some replacement for GetAdaptersInfo() in Linux or any way to implement this.