# Getting network statistics in C using the Netapi32 library

Tags: winapi, netapi32

I want to display the network statistics but can't get this code to work. The
`NetStatisticsGet()` function returns a success status but when I print the buffer contents it displays the same thing on every run. What am I doing wrong? The official Windows docs are not very helpful.

Here's the entire code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <lmstats.h>
#include <lmapibuf.h>

NET_API_STATUS status;
LPWSTR lpwsn = L"LanmanWorkstation";
LPBYTE lpBuf;
DWORD dwSize = 0;

int main() {
    while (1) {
        /* Print network stats at 500 ms intervals */
        status = NetStatisticsGet(NULL, lpwsn, 0, 0, &lpBuf);
        printf("lpbuf: %p\n", lpBuf);

        if (status == NERR_Success) {
            LPSTAT_WORKSTATION_0 pStats = (LPSTAT_WORKSTATION_0)lpBuf;
            NetApiBufferSize (lpBuf, &dwSize);

            for (int i = 0; i < dwSize; i++) printf("%02x", lpBuf[i]);
            printf("\n\n");
            
        } else {
            printf("status code %d\n", status);
            return 0;
        }
        Sleep(500);
    }
    NetApiBufferFree(lpBuf);
    return 0;
}
```

Linking:

```
gcc netstats.c -lNetapi32
```

Output:

```
lpbuf: 0000025805c75660
432e32876ce0d901307f080000000000850200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000009e3d08000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000340000000000000000000000000000004c4d454dd800000038d08401f67f00000000000000000000

lpbuf: 0000025805c74000
432e32876ce0d901307f080000000000860200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000009e3d08000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000340000000000000000000000000000004c4d454dd800000038d08401f67f00000000000000000000

lpbuf: 0000025805c76160
432e32876ce0d901307f080000000000870200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000009e3d08000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000340000000000000000000000000000004c4d454dd800000038d08401f67f00000000000000000000

lpbuf: 0000025805c768d0
432e32876ce0d901307f080000000000880200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000009e3d08000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000340000000000000000000000000000004c4d454dd800000038d08401f67f00000000000000000000
```

Edit: So I did print the field values individually but most of the fields are still zero. The `SmbsTransmitted` field keeps incrementing by one every iteration, the `UseCount`, `StatisticsStartTime`, `BytesReceived`, `BytesTransmitted` fields are nonzero but constant with every iteration whereas all other fields stay zero. Can anyone help me understand what's happening here?

Comment: Beyond the fact you're freeing the buffer too early, NetStatisticsGet is for getting Lanman Workstation (or Server) statistics (ie: when a client connects to a server's share like \\server\share). If you want TCP/IP statistics, etc. you might want to use IP Helper API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/

Comment: @SimonMourier "*you're freeing the buffer too early*" - don't you mean too late? The loop needs to free the buffer on every iteration that is successful, not when the loop ends.

Comment: @vibhav950 "*when I print the buffer contents it displays the same thing on every run*" - look at the output you have shown more carefully, it is NOT the same each time. The 17th byte is changing value: 85, 86, 87, 88, ... That byte is within the `STAT_WORKSTATION_0::SmbsReceived` field. Rather than printing the raw bytes, you should print the field values that are accessible via your casted `pStats` pointer

Comment: @RemyLebeau - ow, sure, I confused the call to NetApiBufferSize with a call to NetApiBufferFree, I saw lpBuf freed before using lpBuf :-)

Comment: I am freeing the buffer on every iteration and setting the pointer to NULL before passing it to NetStatisticsGet() on the next iteration, the code just unintentionally got modified here. But seems like the function does not measure what I thought it did, referring to @SimonMourier's comment.

Comment: @vibhav950 There is a recently uploaded Microsoft [NetworkListManager](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/44d192fd7ec6f2422b7d023891c5f805ada2c811/Samples/NetworkListManager) sample which you can refer to

Comment: These API can get the statistics of network settings, especially *Network List Manager API* that I have tested in the Microsoft [NetworkListManager](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/44d192fd7ec6f2422b7d023891c5f805ada2c811/Samples/NetworkListManager) sample. Does the community wiki work for you?

Answer (score 0):

As @SimonMourier said, use [IP Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/) and [Network List Manager API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/nla/about-the-network-list-manager-api). See [Getting Started with IP Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/iphlp/getting-started-with-ip-helper) and [Get network profile associated with a network adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76562538/get-network-profile-associated-with-a-network-adapter) for more information.